# "Why commands ran in Dockerfile aren't creating persistent files in container?"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Simple commands I run in a Dockerfile are executed when I run `docker-compose build`, however files they create aren't shown when I run `docker-compose up` and look inside the container.

I have been trying to run some dockerized ruby and node applications, but I keep running in the same problem. Here I present a minimal version of my problem.

I have this file structure:

```
myapp
|-----Dockerfile
|-----docker-compose.yml
|-----checkFiles.py
```

`Dockerfile` is

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN ls
RUN echo "this is a test" > myfile.txt
RUN ls
RUN cat myfile.txt

CMD python3 checkFiles.py
```

`docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/myapp'
```

and, finally, `checkFiles.py` is a program to check if there is in current directory a file called `Dockerfile` and a file called `myfile.txt`:

```py
import time
from pathlib import Path
import sys

config = Path('Dockerfile')
if config.is_file():
    print("Dockerfile exists!")
else:
    print("Dockerfile doesn't exist!")

config = Path('myfile.txt')
if config.is_file():
    print("myfile.txt exists!")
else:
    print("myfile.txt doesn't exist!")

print("Waiting for Death...")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep( 100 )
```

When I run `docker-compose build` I can see that originally there is nothing in container (`ls` returns nothing), then I create a file called `myfile.txt`, which is checked to exist by commands `ls` and `cat`.

```
Step 6/7 : RUN cat myfile.txt
 ---> Running in 51491381d2b8
this is a test
```

However

when I run `docker-compose up` output is

```
myapp_1  | Dockerfile exists!
myapp_1  | myfile.txt doesn't exist!
myapp_1  | Waiting for Death...
```

Indicating there is no `myfile.txt` in container.
Moreover, if I open another terminal and try to see inside the container, I can also check there is indeed no `myfile.txt`:

```
$ docker-compose exec myapp ls
Dockerfile          checkFiles.py       docker-compose.yml
```

However, I can create a file in container using the `exec` command, and it will instantly appear in my local directory too (according to `volume` set on `docker-compose.yml`)

```
$ docker-compose exec myapp echo "created using exec" > test.txt
```

File `test.txt` instantly appears also in my local directory.

I know my question has been long, but I wanted to cover all details, so
Why `Dockerfile` `RUN` commands seem to create files that later vanish (and are not updated in my local directory)?

Answer (score 1):

```
volumes:
  - '.:/usr/src/myapp'
```

You're mounting the current directory over top of `/usr/src/myapp`, so everything that's in there is hidden underneath the mount.

Perhaps you should `COPY` your application files into the container instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Yes! Indeed, it was it that was hidding my `myfile.txt` file. But I still want to have comunication between my local files and container files for development. Is there another way I can do that? Or is there a way I can run Dockerfile `RUN` commands after the volume has been mounted?

Comment: I mean, suppose I have built my container without `volume`, using `COPY`. Suppose I want to edit myfile.txt while the container is up, using my local machine text editor. How can I do that?